# A Copy vs. a Reference

Tags: c#

Why does this code result in both shipment.Items.Count and combinedShipment.Items.Count equal to zero?

```
private static InboundShipment CombineLikeIsbns(InboundShipment shipment)
{
    // shipment.Items has a count of 3

    var distinctIsbns = shipment.Items.Select(i => i.ISBN).Distinct().ToList();

    var combinedShipment = shipment;
    combinedShipment.Items = new List<InboundShipmentItem>();

    // Now both combinedShipment and shipment have an empty List in the .Items property

    ...

    return combinedShipment;
}
```

[EDIT]
And what can I do to avoid having shipment.Items set to new List when I set combinedShipment.Items to the same?

Comment: We need information about the `InboundShipment` type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This statement:

```
var combinedShipment = shipment;
```

copies the value of `shipment` into `combinedShipment`. Assuming `InboundShipment` is a class, the value of `shipment` is a *reference* - not an object itself.

So now we have two variables which both refer to the same object. It doesn't matter which variable you use to make a change to the object - the change will be visible *via* both variables.

If you want to create a new "copy" of the original object, you'll have to do that explicitly. It's hard to know exactly what you'd need to do here, as you haven't given us much information about the `InboundShipment` type.

See my [article on value types and reference types](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html) for more details. Note that this is a *vital* part of C# and .NET, and you should become confident on it before going further - advanced topics such as LINQ (with its lambda expressions, deferred execution etc) will be hard to understand until you've got a good handle on the basics.

Comment: Yep.  I'm embarrassed. Thanks Jon.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
var combinedShipment = shipment;
```

sets the combinedShipment reference to point at the same instance as shipment.  So when you clear the items on combinedShipment, it clears them for that one single instance.

Answer (score 1):

The assignment `var combinedShipment = shipment;` causes both `combinedShipment` and `shipment` to refer to exactly the same object. It's a little bit like sticking two different labels on the same cardboard box.

So the following line where you take all the items out of the box labeled `combinedShipment` also causes the box labeled `shipment` to be emptied.  Because they're just the same box with two different labels.

If you want to create a new shipment object that has different items, you'll need to start by doing exactly that: Create a new shipment object.

```
var combinedShipment = new InboundShipment();
```

The actual code might not be able to look exactly like that.  Assuming you want some of `combinedShipment`'s properties to be the same as `shipment`'s, you'll have to manually make sure that happens.  Depending on how `InboundShipment` is designed, that will require either passing the desired values into the constructor, setting the desired values via properties, or a mix of both.